# Showing Django Many to Many in template

Tags: django

I want to list the players in a game in a template

```
<h1>{{ game.name }}</h1>

<p> Players: </p>{{game.Players.all|join:", "}}
```

The code above gives me the names separated by commas but I want to do something like

```
{% for Player in Players %}
    {{Player}}
{% endfor %}
```

My models.py is

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    bday = models.DateField(default=0)
    block = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Sports = models.ManyToManyField(Sport)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Game(models.Model):
    Players = models.ManyToManyField(PlayerProfile)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for player in game.Players.all %}
    {{ player.bday }} # or another field you want
{% endfor %}
```

Should help

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Would you know of any way to access the players bday? Thanks again.